# convert asp Javascript to php Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this javascript  and its work good in asp.net,,, but I try this script in the same example in php but not work whats the wrong ?

I have lable include value ,, I try get the lable value and insert it in hidden field ,

this is my script

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

      function Calculate() {
           var Txt_Percent = document.getElementById('<%= txt_Percent.ClientID %>');
           var Txt_Fix = document.getElementById('<%= txt_Fix.ClientID %>');
           if (document.getElementById('<%= rad_Fix.ClientID %>').checked == true) {
           document.getElementById('txt_Percent').disabled = true;

           var lblReadCost = document.getElementById('<%= lbl_Read_Cost.ClientID %>');

           var lblReadCostValue;
           var Lab_Read_Net = document.getElementById('<%= lbl_Read_Net.ClientID %>');
           var hf_Read_Net = document.getElementById('<%= hf_Read_Net.ClientID %>');


           if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')
               lblReadCostValue = lblReadCost.textContent;
           else
               lblReadCostValue = lblReadCost.innerText;





           if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')
               Lab_Read_Net.textContent = (eval(lblReadCostValue) - eval(Txt_Fix.value));
           else
               Lab_Read_Net.innerText = (eval(lblReadCostValue) - eval(Txt_Fix.value));

           hf_Read_Net.value = (eval(lblReadCostValue) - eval(Txt_Fix.value));

           if (document.getElementById('<%= txt_Fix.ClientID %>').value == '') {
               Lab_Read_Net.innerText = (eval(lblReadCostValue));
           }



        }

        if (document.getElementById('<%= rad_Percent.ClientID %>').checked == false) {

           Txt_Percent.value = "";
        }


     }

     </script>

    <script type="text/ecmascript">

    function Calculate1() {


        var Txt_Fix = document.getElementById('<%= txt_Fix.ClientID %>');
        var Txt_Percent = document.getElementById('<%= txt_Percent.ClientID %>');

        if (document.getElementById('<%= rad_Percent.ClientID %>').checked == true) {
            document.getElementById('txt_Fix').disabled = true;

            var lblReadCost1 = document.getElementById('<%= lbl_Read_Cost.ClientID %>');
            var lblReadCostValue1;

            var Lab_Read_Net = document.getElementById('<%= lbl_Read_Net.ClientID %>');
            var hf_Read_Net = document.getElementById('<%= hf_Read_Net.ClientID %>');


            if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')
                lblReadCostValue1 = lblReadCost1.textContent;
            else
                lblReadCostValue1 = lblReadCost1.innerText;


            if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')
                Lab_Read_Net.textContent = (eval(lblReadCostValue1) - eval(Txt_Percent.value));




            var x = (eval(lblReadCostValue1) * eval(Txt_Percent.value) / 100);

            Lab_Read_Net.innerText = (eval(lblReadCostValue1) - parseInt(x));


            hf_Read_Net.value = (eval(lblReadCostValue1) - parseInt(x));

            if (document.getElementById('<%= txt_Percent.ClientID %>').value == '') {
                Lab_Read_Net.innerText = (eval(lblReadCostValue1));
            }
        }




        if (document.getElementById('<%= rad_Fix.ClientID %>').checked == false) {

            Txt_Fix.value = "";
        }



    }
   </script>
```

Comment: Really you need a converter? just change your ids

Answer (score 0):

This does not work in PHP:

```
<%= txt_Percent.ClientID %>
```

Because you don't have these objects. Input fields are just static HTML in php. You have to set the ID's you set in your PHP yourself in the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the asp response.write (`<%=xxxx %>`) for php echos `<?php echo $xxx; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
// ASP
var Txt_Percent = document.getElementById('<%= txt_Percent.ClientID %>');
```

Convert your objects into array then use like

```
// PHP
var Txt_Percent = document.getElementById("<?php echo $txt_Percent['ClientID']; ?>");
```